# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined javascript error and with highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Straight Away to the point that I am downloading a PDF of chart where I got the above exception on browser console saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

Not sure why I am getting this error. I have other reports which are downloading good. But some times I  get this issue. Piece of code that i am running is below.

I am exactly getting the issue at this line `window[theSelectedChart].exportChart({`

Can any one help me out there. Thanks in advance.

```
if(theSelectedChart == 'somechart') {
   if(Shortform.chartType == 'bubble'){
        var maxDays = Math.max.apply(Math, Shortform.activeDays);
        var minDays = Math.min.apply(Math, Shortform.activeDays);
        window[theSelectedChart].xAxis[0].setExtremes(minDays - 1, maxDays + 1);
    } else {
         window[theSelectedChart].xAxis[0].setExtremes(0, categoriesLength);  
    }
} else { 
    window[theSelectedChart].xAxis[0].setExtremes(0, categoriesLength - 1);
}
window[theSelectedChart].exportChart({
    type: "application/pdf",
    url: 'export-chart/',
    filename: localizedShortformExportFilenames[key],
    sourceWidth:(categoriesLength * 12 > 600) ? categoriesLength * 12 : 800,
},{
    scrollbar : {
        enabled : false,
    },
    chart : {
         marginTop : getMarginTop(selectedThumbnail),
         spacingRight : 30,
    },
    title: {
         y:5,
    },
    subtitle : {
         y : 15
    },
});
```

Comment: It looks like `xAxis` probably doesn't exist. You should try to debug your code with `console.log`s and breakpoints.

Comment: Or possibly `localizedShortformExportFilenames` is the one not defined. Hard for us to know with what you gave us.

Comment: Even after removing the statements what you are pointing is also failing. Don't know where it was failing...I am kinda tensed...

Comment: It's not enough info to answer directly (we can only guess) what is wrong according to the error. In Chrome dev tools, you can downtrack (by clicking an arrow on the left side of error) stack of functions called to throw that exception. Could you attach such info? Just like [here](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-7C7tAeJcVuk/Ta7twFWl3-I/AAAAAAAAAD8/7slcH4a3Guo/s1600/Screen%2Bshot%2B2011-04-20%2Bat%2B7.24.42%2BAM.png).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use "window" as a variable-name.  It is reserved for use in referencing the browser window inside-of-which you are running JavaScript and other code. For your array of windows, use a different name, perhaps "windw".

Comment: I can't agree: for example `myObject['stuff']` will work perfectly fine for an object with structure: `myObject  = { "stuff": 1 }`. As you can see from the code in the question - his variable can be string or something like `somechart` - that means he is just using this as reference, which will work fine.